# Field and values connection in Storm

Tags: stream, field, tuples, apache-storm

I have a fundamental question in storm. I can clearly understand some basic things. For example i have a **main class** with this code inside:

```
...    
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

builder.setSpout(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID, new SentenceSpout());
builder.setBolt(SPLIT_BOLT_ID, new SplitSentenceBolt()).shuffleGrouping(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID);
builder.setBolt(COUNT_BOLT_ID, new WordCountBolt(), 3).fieldsGrouping(SPLIT_BOLT_ID, new Fields("word"));
builder.setBolt(REPORT_BOLT_ID, new ReportBolt()).globalGrouping(COUNT_BOLT_ID);
...
```

and i understand that **1st** element(ex. "SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID") is the id of the bolt/spout in order to show the connection between 2 of them. The **2nd** element(ex.new SentenceSpout()) specifies the spout or bold that we set in our topology. **3rd** element marks the num of tasks that we need for this certain bolt spout.

Then we use .fieldsGrouping or .shuffleGrouping etc to specify the type of grouping and then between the parenthesis the **1st** element is the connection with the bolt/spout that takes the input and the **2nd** (ex. new Fields("word")) determines the fields that we will group by.

Inside the code of one of the bolts:

```
public class SplitSentenceBolt extends BaseRichBolt{
    private OutputCollector collector;

    public void prepare(Map config, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        this.collector.emit(a, new Values(word, time, name));
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }
}
```

At `this.collector.emit(a, new Values(word, time, name));` a is the stream_ID and values(...) are the elements of the tuple.

At `declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));` word must be one of the previous values. **Am i right to all the previous?**

**So my question is:**  that in `declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));` **word** must be the same with **word** in `this.collector.emit(a, new Values(word, time, name));` and the same with the **word** in `builder.setBolt(COUNT_BOLT_ID, new WordCountBolt(), 3).fieldsGrouping(SPLIT_BOLT_ID, new Fields("word"));` ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **number and order** of the fields you declare in declareOutputFields should match the fields you emit.

Two changes I'd recommend:

1. For now use the default stream by omitting the first parameter: `collector.emit(new Values(word, time, name));`
2. Make sure you declare the same number of fields: `declarer.declare(new Fields("word", "time", "name"));`

Comment: So if i understood correctly i must have the same number of elements and with the same order to emit(..) and to declare(new Fields(...)) but i can use different names? Example: collector.emit(new Values(word, time, name)); declarer.declare(new Fields("spittedward", "timestamp", "firstname"));. Am i right?

Comment: @Puteolana Sure, you can do that if you want.

Comment: how to do it in case of custom objects new Fields(customObject) where customObject is a POJO ?